# Why doesn't this Dart code with generic classes and constraints compile?

Tags: dart, generics, constraints

I can't understand why this code doesn't compile.
In my intentions, the following snippet should declare a BaseGenericClass with no constraint on its argument, and a GenericClass deriving from BaseGenericClass with a constraint on type T telling the compiler to accept only classes derived from AbstractArgClass.

```
abstract class BaseGenericClass<T> {
  final T _arg;
 
  BaseGenericClass(this._arg);
}

class GenericClass<T extends AbstractArgClass> extends BaseGenericClass<T> {
  GenericClass() : super(ArgClass());
}

abstract class AbstractArgClass {}

class ArgClass extends AbstractArgClass {}
```

ArgClass derives from AbstractArgClass, still lines 8 raises this error:
The argument type 'ArgClass' can't be assigned to parameter type 'T'

Comment: `AbstractArgClass` is a common base type for `T` and for `ArgClass`.  There is no other relationship between `T` and `ArgClass`; one is not substitutable for the other.  For example, imagine `Mammal` being a common base type for `Cat` and for `Dog`.  You could not use a `Dog` where a `Cat` is expected.

Comment: That should be enough: the compiler should know that T and ArgClass both extend AbstractArgClass (like Cat and Dog extend Mammal), so I should be able to use T or ArgClass (Cat or Dog) wherever I specified AbstractArgClass (Mammal)

Comment: No, it is not legal.  As I said even though `Cat` and `Dog` are `Mammal`s, you cannot pass a `Dog` where a `Cat` is expected.  Suppose you had some other class `DifferentArgClass` that also extends `AbstractArgClass`, and then you used `GenericClass<DifferentArgClass>`.  `DifferentArgClass` would satisfy the generic constraint of `T extends AbstractArgClass`, but `super(ArgClass())` would be illegal since you cannot pass an `ArgClass` where `BaseGenericClass`'s constructor expects `DifferentArgClass`.

Comment: But you are. `GenericClass` *unconditionally* attempts to invoke the `ArgClass` constructor regardless of what `T` is (and `T` might not be an `ArgClass` at all).  Therefore the `GenericClass` constructor is not legal.  The bottom line is that for `GenericClass` to work, `GenericClass` cannot be responsible for constructing the `T` instance.  That responsibility needs to be pushed to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is correct here. `ArgClass` and `AbstractArgClass` in fact do not extend `T`, and I can't see a way to tell them that `T` is meant to be `ArgClass`.

It should work if you change it like this:

```
class GenericClass<T extends AbstractArgClass> extends BaseGenericClass<T> {
  GenericClass(T t) : super(t);
}
```

You have to supply your instance of `ArgClass` to the constructor of `GenericClass`:

```
final g = GenericClass(ArgClass());
```

If you do not want to provide this from ouside, you can add a static function to make a new instance, like:

```
class GenericClass<T extends AbstractArgClass> extends BaseGenericClass<T> {
  GenericClass._(T t) : super(t);

  static GenericClass make() => GenericClass._(ArgClass());
}
```

and get an instance:

```
final g = GenericClass.make();
```

Comment: Your solution works around the problem, but I cannot understand why... still it gave me a hint (new code in the anser below)

Answer (score 0):

Ber's answer apparently works around the problem introducing a sort of intermediation... I tried to create a useless IntermediateClass that just introduces the restrictions on the type T (T has to derive from AbstractArgClass). This works!!!
AnotherGenericClass, as expected, does not compile because AnotherClass does not extend AbstractArgClass.

Still the question: why?
It looks like a compiler glitch to me, do you agree?

```
abstract class BaseGenericClass<T> {
  final T _arg;
  
  BaseGenericClass(this._arg);
}

class IntermediateClass<T extends AbstractArgClass> extends BaseGenericClass<T> {
  IntermediateClass(T arg) : super(arg);
}

class GenericClass extends IntermediateClass {
  GenericClass() : super(ArgClass());  
}

abstract class AbstractArgClass {}

class ArgClass extends AbstractArgClass {}

class AnotherClass {}

class AnotherGenericClass extends IntermediateClass {
  AnotherGenericClass() : super(AnotherClass());
}
```

Comment: No, not a compiler glitch as I explained in the question comments.  The `IntermediateClass` isn't necessary (and in this case, harmful since it loses type information).  The important difference between this code and your original code is that the construction of `ArgClass` is not done by generic classes (and despite their names, `GenericClass` and `AnotherGenericClass` in this answer are not generic).

Comment: Sorry fore the delay, I see your point, you're and were absolutely right.
BTW: To give credit where credit is due... I can't mark your comment as an answer, can I?